# allow editor/author to publish others posts but not publish their own

Tags: posts, user-roles, permissions

Im trying to disallow editors from publishing their own post, I would like editors to only be allowed to publish others submitted posts.

I would like contributors and authors to submit their posts for review. I would like the editor to approve these posts for publishing, but I do not want the editor to be able to publish their own posts.

I have been trying some plugins, and im not able to get this working.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

It probably is impossible to do without a specialized plugin.

That said, one way to achieve it that comes to my mind would be to write a plugin that would add a custom capability "publish_others_posts", and then in all the places where the "publish_posts" capability is checked, replace it with a check for "publish_posts" if the post is of the user, and if not, check for "publish_others_posts". Then revoke the editors the "publish_posts" permission and grant them the "publish_others_posts" permission, e.g. using the User Role Editor plugin.

Comment: how would i got about adding this custom capability

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but currently still the top hit in Google.
Currently it's not possible without a workaround. So I've added it as feature request to WordPress for publish_others_posts.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/51334